# MingW: cannot find -lpthreadGC2

Tags: linker, find, pthreads, cmake

I get the error

> cannot find -lpthreadGC2

when building my program. The strange thing is that it is definitly there. I build using cmake, in combinition with Eclipse and MingW. All other libraries work perfectly fine (they are set up in the same way).

With cmake I can use the command `message()` to give out messages. I checked that all include paths and lib pathes are set correctly with message(). I can confirm this in the Eclipse project settings, the paths are set (including pthreads.h works perfectly, it is found).
The command `target_link_libraries(MyApp "libpthreadGC2.a")` is also executed (checked again with `message()`).

Summary: all pathes are set, all linking is ordered to cmake. Eclipse knows all the paths. But the MingW linker doesn't find the library. Any ideas where I should look for the errors?

Comment: I assume you've double- and triple-checked everything for typos and misspellings? Usually, you either use a full path name to a library file (/path/to/libpthreadGC2.a) or a CMake target name (but only for targets you're building) as the argument to target_link_libraries. Did you try using the full path name of the lib in the target_link_libraries call?

Comment: Yes, I even tried to copy-paste the directory names directly. Every occurance and call is checked with a cmake message(). I also compared to all the other libs in case I missed a command: Nope, it's everything there. The lib itself (.a file) is in the folder.

I have no clue what other places I could check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, just found it out...

The cmake command `add_executable()` has to come **after** the `link_directories()` call... But I still wonder, why this only was for the pthreads lib and not for the others...

Comment: Maybe all the others are in locations that do not need to be specified in link_directories calls? If you use the full path to the library in target_link_libraries instead of using a call to link_directories, then this should have just worked.